# Creating Organization in Liferay using OrganizationLocalServiceUtil.addOrganization?

Tags: liferay

I am creating an `Organization` in Liferay using:

```
OrganizationLocalServiceUtil.addOrganization (
                userId, parentOrganizationId, name,
                type, recursable, regionId, countryId,
                statusId, comments, false, serviceContext);
```

Following are my confusions:

1. Why we need `parentOrganizationId`?
2. What does organization `status` refer to?
3. Why `ServiceContext`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in this [documentation](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/OrganizationLocalServiceUtil.html#addOrganization%28long,%20long,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20long,%20long,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContext%29).

From the documentation as it is:

`userId` - the primary key of the creator/owner of the organization
`parentOrganizationId` - the primary key of the organization's parent organization
`name` - the organization's name
`type` - the organization's type
`recursable` - whether the permissions of the organization are to be inherited by its sub-organizations
`regionId` - the primary key of the organization's region
`countryId` - the primary key of the organization's country
`statusId` - the organization's workflow status
`comments` - the comments about the organization
`site` - whether the organization is to be associated with a main site
`serviceContext` - the organization's service context (optionally null). Can set asset category IDs, asset tag names, and expando bridge attributes for the organization.

**To add to the above documentation some specifics in response to your question:**

> Why we need `parentOrganizationId`?

Liferay has a concept of heirarchical Organization structure, so you can have levels of Organizations.
So if you want to create top-level Organization then use [`com.liferay.portal.model.OrganizationConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_ORGANIZATION_ID`](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/model/OrganizationConstants.html#DEFAULT_PARENT_ORGANIZATION_ID) to pass for 
`parentOrganizationId`

> What does organization status refer to?

Liferay has [workflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workflow) (like Kaleo-workflow) for various assets. If you don't want to use this than pass [`com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowConstants.STATUS_APPROVED][4]`

> Why ServiceContext?

This you can pass as `null` as stated.
Basically you can think of this class as a collection of different general methods and attributes like Expando, asset-tags, asset-categories etc which can be passed as a single argument by being enclosed in the ServiceContext object rather than as individual arguments and making the method call tedious.
Here is the [documentation](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/ServiceContext.html).
Here are some more details for you to understand this better: [Development Guide](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/service-conte-1) & [Wiki](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/ServiceContext+Pattern).

Comment: In a sample code,  
GetterUtil.getInteger(PropsUtil.get("sql.data.com.liferay.portal.model.ListType.organization.status"));
is done to get organization status id , which returns 12017 . I can't get what is this number referring to .

Comment: This Id is from the `ListType` table. This table contains all the master data for different type of lists like `Title` list for User, `Suffix` for User, `Phone Types`, `Address Types` etc. And this is the ID which liferay uses by default.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer: [There's javadoc](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/OrganizationLocalService.html#addOrganization%28long,%20long,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20long,%20long,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContext%29)

Somewhat longer:

- Organizations have an implicit hierarchy - thus, if you create an organization, you might as well create it at the intended position in the hierarchy, thus parentOrganizationId.
- You might want to try ListTypeConstants.ORGANIZATION_STATUS_DEFAULT as the status you give
- Typically, Liferay stores owners or other data with created entities (e.g. for later permission checks). This is data that can be retrieved from serviceContext.

Answer (score 2):

A working snippet for Liferay 6.2 for top level organizations is:

```
ServiceContext serviceContext = ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(request); //or null
Organization organization = OrganizationServiceUtil.addOrganization(
                OrganizationConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_ORGANIZATION_ID,
                organizationName,
                OrganizationConstants.TYPE_REGULAR_ORGANIZATION,
                RegionConstants.DEFAULT_REGION_ID,
                CountryConstants.DEFAULT_COUNTRY_ID,
                ListTypeConstants.ORGANIZATION_STATUS_DEFAULT,
                "",
                false,
                serviceContext
        );
```

The comment of Olaf Kock before is correct, and using

```
WorkflowConstants.STATUS_APPROVED
```

for the status will yield a

```
com.liferay.portal.NoSuchListTypeException.
```

I would upvote him, if this would not be a new account.